# What is the difference between "personas" and "gente"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, uso-de-palabras

I was translating a sentence for school en Español and I came across the word "`people`." I looked it up on [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto%7Ces%7Cpeople%0A) and it gave me "`personas`" and also "`gente`." What is the difference between the two, and the use case for each of these nouns?

Comment: There is a third translation for _People_: _Pueblo_ (in the sense of _nation_) for example _"One of the guiding mantras of the twentieth century was the self-determination of `peoples`"_ or _"`People`'s Republic of China"_

Comment: Note that `gente` does not have a plural form, even though some people use it. It is wrong and may make you sound illiterate.

Comment: In México there is a common phrase to refer to someone as being `buena gente`, which means someone is good, nice, trustable: `Conocí a Juan, parece que es buena gente.` can be translated as `I met Juan, he seems like a nice guy.`. However, there is no such phrase as `mala gente`, it is only used in the positive way.

Comment: I'm sorry, the phrase `mala gente` does exist, it's just is much less common to hear. There's even a song by colombian singer Juanes called [Mala gente](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mala_Gente_%28song%29)

Comment: @alonso.torres that is wrong. Could you indicate where on http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=gente does it specify that gente does not have a plural? "gentes" may not be common, but it can be used as "pueblos" (groups of people): "Los pueblos del oriente" == "las gentes del oriente". Uncommon, but not incorrect.

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza While 'gentes' has a widespread use, as that page you linked us to mentions:
1. f. Pluralidad de personas.
It's already a plural, so by saying 'gentes', you're making a plural out of a plural.

Comment: @JATerroba Yes. I know. And it's a valid plural of a plural. A squad is a group of people. You can have many squads. Where does it say you can't have a plural of a plural? If you can think of it as "one entity" you can think of "many entities".

Comment: Miguel explains it better below. But I'll give it a shot.
'Gente' is akin to 'people' in English. You can use 'Gentes' the same way as you would use 'Peoples' in English, 'Peoples' is not the same as 'Persons', they describe different things.
And using 'squad' as an example doesn't really work, since a squad is a singular entity, composed of many units, but it remains a single thing. People is a plurality of entities by itself. If you want to say 'a people', then you're already using another definition of the word, one that can be pluralized. Same deal in Spanish.

Comment: @JATerroba good concise answer!

Comment: Is it correct to say that `gente = people` and `persona = person`? After all, `You are a nice person` gets translated to `Eres una buena persona` and not `Eres una buena gente`

Comment: personas is to persons as gente is to people. That's the easiest explanation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The distinction is easier to see when you consider things in terms of countability. In this sense, `personas` is the plural of `persona`, refers to *many people*, and can be used when counting. On the other hand `gente` is a singular noun, refers to *a group of people* or *many people in general*  and usually isn't used when specifing numbers.

**Example in terms of counting:**

> ○   "Hay veinte *personas* en esa casa." => "There are twenty (individual) persons in that house."
>
> X   "Hay veinte gente en esa casa." => "There is (a whole of) twenty people in that house."

**Example in terms of not counting:**

> ○   "Toda la *gente* está esperando pacientemente." => "All (of) the people (as a whole) are waiting patiently."

One last thing to note is that while `gente` *isn't* interchangeable with `personas`, the opposite isn't necessarily true. In cases where emphasis or more formality is desired, `personas` can be used without specifying a number. Thus in the second example, the sentence could also be written as:

> ○   "Todas las personas están esperando pacientemente." => "All (of) the (individual) persons are waiting patiently."

This is perfectly valid, but sounds a bit awkward for daily use. Regional usage will differ in this fact, I'm sure. That said, `personas` can make a good fallback if you're unsure whether or not you should use `gente`.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that "Todas las personas están esperando pacientemente" (marked there as wrong) is a perfectly valid Spanish sentence.

Comment: @Telaclavo It was never my intention to make it seem like that sentence was incorrect. I reorganized the answer a bit and I think it's cleared things up. Anyways, feel free to edit it more if you still don't think it's clear enough. :)

Comment: @Miguel I said it because there was an "X" just before the sentence, and thought that it could mislead someone. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I couldn't have explained it better. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Gente is called a "collective" noun, for "people," in general.

Persona(s), on the other hand, refer to INDIVIDUAL "people."

Answer (score 0):

Creo y espero no equivocarme, que la palabra "gente" siempre se ha referido a una multitud o a mas de una persona. Si yo digo, tu, (o en mi caso) vos sos una buena persona, sería, para mi modo de ver las cosas y mas que nada y MUY importante, lo que me enseñaron en la escuela, es mas que equivocado decirte que vos sos buena "gente".

Comment: Traté de editarlo, no pude...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure that any of these examples are crystal clear, so let me give it a try:

Persona/s= An individual or several individuals of the human race. Example: Hablé con una persona de la organización (I spoke with A PERSON from the organización).

Gente= a set of "personas" forming a group. Example: Hablé con la gente de la organización (I spoke with THE PEOPLE from the organization).

Persona/s are individual people, or several people, but in principle you could count them up. So saying "me gusta las personas aqui" (I like the people here) is wrong. If you like a person "here," then you could for example say "me gusta una persona se llama Beatriz (I like a person named Beatriz. That's not wrong, but it sounds stilted.

Gente are a group of people. You couldn't literally count them up yourself. You could say "me gusta la gente aqui" (I like the people here). Not one person but everybody collectively.

Answer (score -2):

I happen to speak French, so the differences are obvious to me.

In English, we use the word people for different meanings:

Few people (individuals or persons) came to my party. In Spanish I would use personas.

People (in general, humans) like ice cream. In Spanish, I would use gentes.

The people (of a nation) voted for independence. In Spanish, I would use pueblo.

Comment: Por favor, date cuenta de que este sitio es sobre el idioma español, y esta respuesta no clarifica para nada ni ,gente’ ni ‘personas’. Comparar con otros idiomas está bien, pero tienes que clarificar las diferencias de las palabras ‘gente’ y ‘personas’